# Minimum value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, minimum

I have set a minimum value for 4 things and I encountered a problem. All 4 things have a minimum value of the first thing. When we move the slider, then everything goes back to normal and works fine. Where is the problem?

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/57nv61a1/

```js
 $('#field2').rangeslider({
        polyfill:false,
        onInit:function(){
        
            $('#input2').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
        },
        onSlide:function(position, value){
            $('.content #input2').val(value);
        },
        onSlideEnd:function(position, value){
        }
    });
    // Change the value of input field when slider changes
    $('#field2').on('input', function() {
        $('#input2').val(this.value);
        console.log('$'+$('#input2').val());
    });
    // Change the value of slider field when input changes
    $('#input2').on('input', function() {
        if (this.value.length == 0) $('#field2').val(0).change();

        $('#field2').val(this.value).change();
    });
```

```html
<label for="medical-expenses">Medical Expenses</label>
<span class="label1">$ <input type="number" id="input1" min="1" max="10000"></input></span>
<input id="field1" name="field1" type="range" min="1" max="10000" value="0" data-rangeslider>

<label for="vehicle-damage">Vehicle Damage</label>
<span class="label2">$ <input type="number" id="input2" min="2" max="10000"></input></span>
<input id="field2" name="field2" type="range" min="2" max="10000" value="0" data-rangeslider>
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit more in detail please so we can help you better

Comment: You repeated the same code 4 times because you have 4 sliders. If you had 100 sliders, I don't think you'd want to copy/paste 100 times the same code.

Comment: @JeremyThille I need to have only 2 sliders

Comment: so you have 2 extra ones in your JSfiddle.

Comment: @FaisalMehmoodAwan I set the minimum value for "Medical Expenses" to 1 (field1), Vehicle Damage to 2 (field2), Lost Income for 3 (field3) and "Rental Vehicle Cost" to 4 (field4). When we run the script: for field2, field3, and field4 shows the minimum value of field1. When we move the slider, the minimum value will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
$('#input4').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
```

selects all the `input[type="range"]`, takes the value of the first one, and assigns it to `$('#input4')`.

Since you copy/pasted the same code 4 times, every input gets initialized with the same value, which is 1.

```
$('#input1').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
$('#input2').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
$('#input3').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
$('#input4').val($('input[type="range"]').val());
```

After you start moving the sliders and then back to the beginning, the value changes, and then, the respective minimum values (1,2,3,4) apply.

The solution, although still very inelegant, would be to manually assign correct initial values :

```
$('#input1').val(1);
$('#input2').val(2);
$('#input3').val(3);
$('#input4').val(4);
```